# How to get my android fingerprint certifica in Android Studio

Tags: android, maps, fingerprint

I am new Android Developer. I am using Mac Os x Lion and Android Studio 2.0.11. 
I will map application so I need sha1 certifica.

how to get fingerprint mac os and Android studio.

thanx.

Sorry bad english.

Answer (score 27):

If you are in Mac, you can use

```
keytool -list -v -keystore  ~/.android/debug.keystore
```

if you don't have password , press enter, and you'll get the answer

Comment: Default password is android

Comment: just enter without password... press enter

Answer (score 8):

If you're in mac os X you just need to use the terminal app.

Open the terminal, cd into the directory where your keystore is, and use the command:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore mykeystore.keystore
```

You'll get an answer like the following:

```
Nome alias: androiddebugkey
Data di creazione: 5-ott-2013
Tipo di voce: PrivateKeyEntry
Lunghezza catena certificati: 1
Certificato[1]:
Proprietario: CN=Luca Adamo, OU=ELbuild, O=ELbuild, L=Pistoia, ST=Pistoia, C=IT
Autorit? emittente: CN=Luca Adamo, OU=ELbuild, O=ELbuild, L=Pistoia, ST=Pistoia, C=IT
Numero di serie: #########
Valido da: Thu Sep 26 19:19:24 CEST 2013 a: Mon Feb 11 18:19:24 CET 2041
Impronte digitali certificato:
     MD5:  ########################################################
     SHA1: ########################################################
     Nome algoritmo firma: SHA1withRSA
     Versione: 3
```

The value you're looking for is the one following SHA1. If you're looking for your debug certificate in Eclipse go to Preferences -> Android -> Build and you'll find it there.

Comment: ~/.android/debug.keystore

Answer (score 0):

you need the path for the android debugging key by default it's on that path ~/.android/debug.keystore
and command keytool -list -v -keystore  will list all the debugging keys in the following path ~/.android/debug.keystore 
the default password for that key is android

```
keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

Comment: To improve your answer, please try to explain what the command does

Comment: @matejkramny thanks a lot for you hint i will do it :)